# How to solve VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED on VM player for Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: virtualbox, 17.04

I have a 64 bit PC and I downloaded `ubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64` and then
I tried to make a Ubuntu VM using Ubuntu 17.04 but is is giving me an error it says `failed to open disk image` here is the trace back.

```
Could not get the storage format of the medium 'C:\Users\User\Downloads\ubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED).

Result Code:  VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80BB0005)
Component:    MediumWrap
Interface:    IMedium {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda}
Callee:       IVirtualBox {0169423f-46b4-cde9-91af-1e9d5b6cd945}
Callee RC:    VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

Any help?

Comment: You should ask this question in a VirtualBox forum or on [superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by re-downloading the ISO file, as it was broken.

so if you are having some problem then check the file size it must be nearly 1.49 GB , depending upon the version you are downloading.

cheers!

Good day